# Bootstrap carousel, changing slide contents on mobile?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel

I am using Bootstrap's carousel. On desktop each slide has 3 div's in it containing text, so with each slide 3 new text boxes are revealed. On mobile this works fine only you can only see the first text box of every slide.

How can I change the distance a slide moves so that I see every text box? Currently the slider slides 3 times, but I need it to slide 9 times on mobile.

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="slider-section">
<div class="container">
    <div id="statistic-slider" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
                <div class="slider-text">Body text</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#statistic-slider" data-slide="prev"></a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#statistic-slider" data-slide="next"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a ResponsivDesign issue I recommand you to add some .col-xx-xx classes to your div.
If you already use Bootstrap you already now that but, you will be able to have a better structure, yours textboxs with a vertical disposition on mobile and horizontal in desktop for example. 
Have a look on [Bootstrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Other solution could be to make two carousels, one for desktop and another for mobile. You will be able to customize the way you want both of them.
The first one with hidden-xs class ([see bootstrap functionalities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-hover-rows)) and its 3 slides. 
The second one with hidden-md hidden-xx ... and having 3*3 distinct slides for example.