# How do I properly change the layout of the bootstrap carousel on mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

On my dektop page my current layout works just fine:

```html
<div id="elementSlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to be able to slide though each element on its own on mobile. For that I would either need to create a second carousel, as the answer to the same question [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007142/bootstrap-carousel-changing-slide-contents-on-mobile) suggests, or change my layout somehow. I would rather change the layout so I don't need to create a second carousel each time. Right now my solutions looks like this:

```js
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  const moveItems = $('.carousel-inner').find('.col-12').each(function () {
    let element = $(this)
    $(this).closest('.carousel-inner').append(element)
  })

  $.when.apply(this, moveItems).done(function () {
    $('.carousel-inner').find('.carousel-item').remove()
    $('.carousel-inner').find('.col-12').each(function (i) {
      if(i === 0) {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="carousel-item active"><div class="row"></div></div>')
      } else {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="carousel-item"><div class="row"></div></div>')
      }
    })
  })
}
```

But it doesn't really work reliably. Does anyone have a better solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/) already has classes that change the number of columns according to the screen size, like `col-12`, `col-md-6`, `col-lg-3`. The easiest way to customize it more would be using [media-queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) for this. So for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-inner {
    // Your CSS
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I know about those. My goal is to only show one of these divs per container-item and slide through each of these elements without braking them underneath each other. I've actually been able to get it done by myself, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Apperently my solution did work after all. I had a css property setting the content of the `carousel-item` to `display: none;`. My solutions works fine on desktop and mobile:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Brecherchef/j0249rwa/55/)

Might not be the cleanest solution but it works for now.